# foreach doesn't display list data in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, foreach

I'm in searching in another answer because my code doesn't work even through it's suppose to work the `c:forEach` to display a list's data in the jsp.

In the servlet's side the code I'm working is

```
List <Alumno> ar = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject re = new JSONObject(jsonObjSt);
JSONArray res = re.getJSONArray("alumno");
Alumno alu;
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) {
        alu = new Alumno(
        res.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"),
        res.getJSONObject(i).getString("ap_pat"),
        res.getJSONObject(i).getString("ap_mat"),
        res.getJSONObject(i).getInt("carrera"),
        res.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("genero")
        );
        ar.add(alu);
    }
request.setAttribute("alumno", ar);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/lista.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

the jsp code where I call the list is

```
<c:forEach items="${alumno}" var="dat">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${dat.nombre}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${dat.ap_pat}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${dat.ap_mat}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

However it doesn't display any data

EDIT: This is the Alumno Structure

```
 public class Alumno{
    public String nombre;
    public String ap_pat;
    public String ap_mat;
    public int carrera;
    public boolean genero;

    public Alumno(String nombre, String ap_pat, String ap_mat, int carrera, boolean genero){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ap_pat = ap_pat;
        this.ap_mat = ap_mat;
        this.carrera = carrera;
        this.genero = genero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share `Alumno` class structure ?

Comment: public class Alumno{
        public String nombre;
        public String ap_pat;
        public String ap_mat;
        public int carrera;
        public boolean genero;
        
        public Alumno(String nombre, String ap_pat, String ap_mat, int carrera, boolean genero){
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.ap_pat = ap_pat;
            this.ap_mat = ap_mat;
            this.carrera = carrera;
            this.genero = genero;
        }
        }

Comment: You should [edit] the question and add the code in the question, not in a comment. Comments cannot be formatted and should be used only for short information.

Comment: I will suggest you try it without the <c:out markup. Just insert a plain <td>${dat.nombre}</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe the framework is looking for a bean with getters as `${dat.nombre}`=>`getNombre()`, `${dat.ap_pat}` => `getAp_pat()` and `${dat.ap_mat}` => `getAp_mat()`. Try adding getters to your `Alumno` bean.

Answer (score 0):

First Check that in java class that you are getting data in alumno. Add getter methods in Alumno that will surely work.

Comment: Yes, my Java class is getting data, so I don't know what could be the problem